# Aggregation based date vertex to get label from different vertex

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, tinkerpop3

```
g.addV('l1').
    property(id, 12347).
    property('submit_time', new Date('Wed May14 10:00:00 PDT 2019')).
  addV('l1').
    property(id, 4522323).
    property('submit_time', new Date('Wed May15 11:00:00 PDT 2019')).
  addV('l1').
    property(id, 2355208312).
    property('submit_time', new Date('Wed May15 11:00:00 PDT 2019')).
  addV('l3').
    property(id, 45678).
    property('start_time', new Date('Fri Apr 24 07:01:36 PDT 2019')).
  addV('l3').
    property(id, 67892).
    property('start_time', new Date('Fri Apr 24 07:01:36 PDT 2019')).
  addV('l3').
    property(id, 678954).
    property('start_time', new Date('Fri Apr 26 23:01:36 PDT 2019')).
    property('condition', "somevalue").
  addE('e1').
    from(V(12347)).
    to(V(45678)).
  addE('e1').
    from(V(12347)).
    to(V(67892)).
  addE('e1').
    from(V(4522323)).
    to(V(678954)).
  addE('e1').
    from(V(2355208312)).
    to(V(45678)).
  iterate()
```

One `l1` vertex can be associated with an edge (`e1`) to multiple different `l3` vertices. I am trying to aggregate the above scenario based on `submit_time` property from `l1`. I have tried the below query.

```
g.V().hasLabel("l1").
  group().
    by(map {(it.get().value("submit_time").getYear() + 1900) + "/" +
            (it.get().value("submit_time").getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
             it.get().value("submit_time").getDate()}).
  unfold().
  project('submitdate','job','jobdesc').
    by(keys).
    by(values).
    by(select(values).unfold().out('e1').has("condition","somevalue").fold()).
  order(local).
    by(keys, incr)
```

It fetches me the below result.

```
==>[job:[v[12347]],jobdesc:[],submitdate:2019/5/14]
==>[job:[v[2355208312],v[4522323]],jobdesc:[v[678954]],submitdate:2019/5/15]
```

In the above result it's aggregating based on `submitdate` and getting me its corresponding `l1` vertex as `job` after aggregation, however my `jobdesc` is empty because it does not satisfy the "has" condition `.has("condition","somevalue")`.

In the 1st result, even though vertex `v[12347]` is considered in aggregation, and have an edge to `v[45678]` and `v[67892]` they do not satisfy the "has condition", so my `jobdesc` is empty. Similarly in the 2nd result, one of my vertex (`v[678954]`) is satisfying the above condition.

Can anyone please help me to get some default value, eg. an empty array for `jobdesc` for each of the job vertex if it does not satisfy the condition and is considered in aggregation?

**Expected output**

```
==>[job:[v[12347]],jobdesc:[[]],submitdate:2019/5/14]
==>[job:[v[2355208312],v[4522323]],jobdesc:[[],v[678954]],submitdate:2019/5/15]
```

Eg: `v[2355208312]` is considered in aggregation for `submitdate` `2019/5/14` but there is no `jobdesc` for it so I am not able to map the index for each job and its corresponding `jobdesc`.

Comment: FYI: Your question wasn't formatted and fixed by black magic, someone actually spent time doing it for you. Next time, you post a question on SO, make sure it's properly formatted and that the code snippets actually work.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I will surely take care of it the next time.

Answer (score 1):

All your query is missing, is an additional `map()` and a `fold()` step.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("l1").
           group().
             by(map {(it.get().value("submit_time").getYear()  + 1900) + "/" +
                     (it.get().value("submit_time").getMonth() +    1) + "/" +
                      it.get().value("submit_time").getDate()}).
           unfold().
           project('submitdate','job','jobdesc').
             by(keys).
             by(values).
             by(select(values).unfold().
                map(out('e1').has("condition","somevalue").fold()). /* for each job */
                fold()).
           order(local).
             by(keys, incr)
==>[job:[v[12347]],jobdesc:[[]],submitdate:2019/5/14]
==>[job:[v[4522323],v[2355208312]],jobdesc:[[v[678954]],[]],submitdate:2019/5/15]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.It solved my problem.